# Calculate percentage of progress between intervals

Tags: php

I'm creating a game, where user can do some progress to move to new levels. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $progress=150; // example
    $percentage=0;
    $level=0;

    if ($progress<300) { $level = 1; $percentage=; }
    if ($progress<600) { $level = 2 $percentage=; }
    if ($progress<900) { $level = 3 $percentage=; }

    echo $percentage;
?>
```

So if the progress is 150 pts for example, the level of this user is 1, and percentage he did to move to new level 2, is 50% (done).

For example if progress is 750 pts, the progress should show 50% (is done) to move to new level 3.

I choosed here simple values, 150 and 750, but I don't know how to calculate if progress is 610, 625 etc...

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to calculate the percentage needed to get to the next level?

Comment: How and where are you adding to your `$progress` variable? You need conditions to satisfy that the user has earned more points and then add to `$progress`.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Please be clear.

Comment: ooh, it's closed now xD well, [this](https://eval.in/151250) might be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the progresses as an array, and loop over them:

```
$progress = 750;
$levels = array(0, 300, 600, 900);

foreach ($levels as $key => $threshold) {
    if ($progress >= $threshold) {
        $level = $key;

        if (isset($levels[$key + 1])) {
            $percentage = 100 * ($progress - $threshold) /
                          ($levels[$key + 1] - $threshold);
        } else {
            // user has passed the final level
            $percentage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great minds think alike :-)

Comment: works good, but what about If I change $progress=150, doesn't show any value. possible to fix?

Comment: I've added level 0 to the array, should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

This works. Could be refactored:

```
if ($progress < 300) { $level = 1; $percentage = (($progress/300) * 100); }
elseif ($progress < 600) { $level = 2; $percentage = (($progress/600) * 100); }
elseif ($progress < 900) { $level = 3; $percentage = (($progress/900) * 100); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic answer:

```
$limits = array( 0, 300, 600, 900);

$found = false;
for ($level = 1; ($level < count($limits)) && !$found; $level++) {
   if ($progress < $limits[$level]) {
       $found = true; 
       break;
   }
}

echo "Level: $level\n";

if ($found) {
    // percentage to next level
    $lower = $limits[$level-1];
    $percentage = ($progress-$lower)/($limits[$level]-$lower);
    echo $percentage;
} else {
    echo "You're a fewking superhero!!";
}
```

Comment: I have added $progress=150; / $level=1; before your code to test, but it return for me  -0.5, you can check please?

Comment: Minor typo change limit to limits

Comment: Still the issue, with my test, it returns -0.5

Comment: Needed to break out of look with correct level - oops

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function.

```
<?php
    $progress=700;
    $_multiples_of=300;
    echo "Progress to next level is ".getProgressPercentage($progress,$_multiples_of);     

    function getProgressPercentage($progress,$multiples_of){
        $level=floor($progress/$multiples_of);//Get the level of the user based on the interval of 300
        $nextLevelValue=$multiples_of * ($level +1);
        $percentageToNextLevel=intval(($progress/$nextLevelValue) *100);
        return $percentageToNextLevel;
     }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dynamic level system where you do not set the xp need to level up static but dynamically. You can define how many levels there must be and what the xp grow factor is between every level.

```
<?php

    $userXp = 1344; // change this to test

    $maxLevel = 12;
    $grow = 0.88;
    $maxFisrtLv = 530;

    $ranks = array();
    for($a = 0; $a <= $maxLevel; $a++){

        if($a == 0){
            $xp = 0;
        }
        elseif($a == 1){
            $xp = $maxFisrtLv;
        }
        else{
            $prev = $a - 1;
            $xp = $maxFisrtLv + ($grow * $ranks[$prev]);
        }

        if($userXp >= $xp){
            $userlevel = $a;
        }

        $ranks[$a] = $xp;
    }

    $xpBlank = $userXp - $ranks[$userlevel];
    $betweenXp = $ranks[$userlevel + 1] - $ranks[$userlevel];
    $progres = number_format($xpBlank / $betweenXp * 100, 2, '.', '');
    $progresall = number_format($userXp / end($ranks) * 100, 2, '.', '');

    $rank = print_r($ranks, true);
    echo "
        userlevel: $userlevel<br>
        progress overall: $progresall%<br>
        progress: $progres%<br>
        xp: $userXp<br>

        <br>
        <br>
        <pre>
            $rank
        </pre>
    ";

?>
```